# How should I remove this bulb?

Tags: bathroom, light-fixture, bulb

My bathroom bulb died and I am trying to replace it, but before I can figure out what sort of bulb to buy I want to remove it so I can take it with me to the store and get an exact one. However I've tried to pull it hard and it won't come out, I'm afraid I might break the connector if I pull any harder so before I mess it up I thought I would ask.

Here is a picture of the little guy (click for full size image):

[image: photo of light fixture]

Comment: This may be a G4 halogen bulb.  I have a similar fixture.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, make sure the fixture is switched off.

Using a small piece of cloth, to protect your fingers in case the bulb breaks, grab the bulb firmly near the base, and rock it *slightly* back and forth (left to right), so that you are alternately pulling on one pin, then the other.   Once the pins start to move you will probably be able to pull it straight out.

If the bulb does break, you should be able to remove the remaining parts with a pair of needle-nose pliers; be sure to apply the force in the direction the pins are pointing so that you don't break them off.

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks Tom! and thanks Niall C for editing to include the picture :D will give it a go right now!.  Edit: Gave it a go with a small cloth and it worked like a charm! again thanks a lot!!

Comment: In other words, wiggle it

Comment: @jeff - well put!